# base64 encode io.Reader

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, base64

Is there a way to take an io.Reader that contains binary data, and read it out base64 encoded.

I see in encoding/base64 there is

```
func NewDecoder(enc *Encoding, r io.Reader) io.Reader
```

but that assumes the io.Reader data is base64 and returns an io.Reader to decode it to binary.

and

```
func NewEncoder(enc *Encoding, w io.Writer) io.WriteCloser
```

which returns a io.Writer to encode binary to base64 but I'm need to use the go-aws-sdk s3manage Uploader, which takes an io.Reader interface.

```
uploader := s3manager.NewUploaderWithClient(svc)
_, err := uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
   Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
  Key:    aws.String(key),
  Body:   input,
})
```

input needs implement the io.Reader interface

The data is large, so I don't want to read the input fully into memory before doing the encoding

Comment: You may be able to do what you want by implementing the [Transformer](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/transform) interface with a wrapper around `base64.Encoding` and the calling [NewReader](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/transform#NewReader)... but I haven't tried this myself so I don't really know if it's doable.

Comment: Seems you are looking for https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Pipe?

Answer (score 11):

The concept of a Pipe is used to change Readers into Writers and vice-versa.

Using an [`io.Pipe`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Pipe), you can copy the source `io.Reader` into the encoder, and pass the [`io.PipeReader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#PipeReader) as the body to be uploaded.

The error handling is a little unusual if you want to pass it through, but it's possible using the [`CloseWithError`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#PipeWriter.CloseWithError) method. Make sure you also note the correct order to close the pipe and encoder.

```
source := strings.NewReader("Hello, World!")

pr, pw := io.Pipe()
encoder := base64.NewEncoder(base64.StdEncoding, pw)

go func() {
    _, err := io.Copy(encoder, source)
    encoder.Close()

    if err != nil {
        pw.CloseWithError(err)
    } else {
        pw.Close()
    }
}()
```

https://play.golang.org/p/qvc1f7kyTeP